# Titanium Alloy Controller wont stay open

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am building an app in Titanium using Alloy. I am trying to open a new controller on a button click, but no matter what is in that controller, it stays for a couple of milliseconds and then closes and goes back to the previous screen?

Code `js` of current screen:

```
$.easy.addEventListener('click', function() {
    openLevel("easy");
});
$.medium.addEventListener('click', function() {
    openLevel("medium");
});
$.hard.addEventListener('click', function() {
    openLevel("hard");
});

function openLevel(difficulty) {
    var levels = Alloy.createController('choose', {difficulty : difficulty}).getView();
    levels.open();
}
```

The `xml` code of the current screen:

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <View class="header">
        <ImageView image="images/logo.png" id="header_logo"></ImageView>
        <Label id="lblLogo"> Patternz</Label>
    </View>
    <View class="content">
        <View class="menu">
            <Button class="menu_item" id="easy">Easy</Button>
            <Button class="menu_item" id="medium">Medium</Button>
            <Button class="menu_item" id="hard">Hard</Button>
        </View>
    </View>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

The `xml` of the new screen:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

There was more content in here, but after removing that to see what the issue was, the issue remained. I cannot open another screen, no matter what the name of the controller, the styling, the xml content, anything. What could be happening?

Comment: what is the name of the controller and view? there is not enough information here to provide much guidance

Comment: @AaronSaunders, the controller and view's name are `mainMenu` and `levels`. There is no other information, that is ALL the code in my application so far

Comment: Something doesn't sound right.  It appears you are opening a controller called 'choose' and assigning it to a variable called levels.  It would be helpful to see the choose.js file.

Comment: @Martin Sorry for the mixup, at time of posting I used the name "choose" and time of the comment, I had changed the controller name to "levels" as a test.

Comment: NP, seeing the code to that controller would still be useful.